# I have a few questions

Tags: sharepoint-online, access

How can you prevent users from editing the quick launch? Right now, any user can change the content of the quick launch.

Users need limited access to view the home page. Is there a fix for this? Right now users have limited access through everyone but external users group. If I revoke the permission they can request access, but approving it fails to add them, even if they are already part of a different site permission group.

How can I prevent users from accessing the site contents page? I managed to block users from the site contents page on subsites, but not the root site.

I am using custom permissions, and I understand these issues may or may not be linked, but I am having trouble finding information on how to troubleshoot and fix these problems. Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you are using modern group connected team sites or not. As it might make a difference on what and how you can change permissions.

By default users will be added to a members group on SharePoint and the default permissions of the members group is edit. That permissions will give them the ability to change the structure of the site (e.g. add metadata columns, change navigation etc.) Best is to change this to contribute. However changing this permissions is disable in the ui on modern group connected team sites.

See this blog post for more detail: https://www.oak3.org/sharepoint/permissions-on-a-group-connected-team-site/

And a discussion on the Tech community: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Change-group-permission-on-connected-group-site/m-p/183633

Comment: I am pretty sure it is a modern team site. I created customized permission groups so that some people could read and some could edit. My intention was to allow editing of content within document libraries, even deleting an item. After some fiddling, I realized my read permission groups work alright, but my write permission group can not only edit content of a library, but they can add new pages, libraries, and even delete libraries! How can I adjust the current permissions to limit users to only adding or deleting content of libraries and not change the structure of the site?

Comment: Right now the edit permission I created allows for managing lists, add items, edit items, delete items, view items, approve items, open items, view versions, delete versions, create alerts, view app pages, and view pages. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ah! I managed to disable users ability to delete libraries and such by revoking the managing lists permission, however on the home page there is a new+ button they can use to make a new page, news post or plan. Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: A new page is the same or new news post is the same type of permission as a new word document, you could see it as content. If you don't want people to have those permissions, you need to stop permissions inheritence on the site pages library and change the permissions van contribute to read.